# how to save adapter.bin model as .pt model

Tags: huggingface, openai-whisper, peft

I have a hugging face `openai-whisper` model `adapter.bin` that has been finetuned using `LoRa`, following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Vaibhavs10/fast-whisper-finetuning/blob/main/README.md). `Adapter.bin` has only the adapter weights. Now I want to save my original model with this adapter weight and get a `finetuned.pt` model that I can load locally. A sample from the code below:

```
peft_model_id = "reach-vb/test" 
language = "en"
task = "transcribe"
peft_config = PeftConfig.from_pretrained(peft_model_id)
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
  peft_config.base_model_name_or_path, load_in_8bit=False, device_map="auto"
)
```

How do I save this model as a `.pt` torch model that I can load using
`model = whisper.load_model('model.pt')`